# Inferred type is not general enough

Tags: haskell, prefix

I'm wondering if a list is a prefix of a second list, using the following code:

```
prefix :: [a] -> [b] -> Bool
prefix [] _ = True
prefix _ [] = False
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) = if (x==y) then prefix xs ys else False
```

But it returns an error:

```
Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : prefix
*** Expected type : [a] -> [b] -> Bool
*** Inferred type : [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

Can someone help me get this to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your type signature claims the two lists can have different types, but they can't.  So the compiler complains that it inferred a type that was less general than the one you asked for.

Answer (score 7):

That's because you're comparing the types you've named `a` and `b` using `(x==y)`. Checking the type of `==`, that means they are the same type, which has an equality test:

```
Prelude> :t (==)
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

So the type signature that is inferred is actually `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`.